# php querystring to pass variable with spaces

Tags: php

I am passing some variable from a page to another and it works fine for me but for the variables which has SPACE its not working...

Here is the code snippet:

```
<?php echo "<a href=test2.php?key=".$row->ean."&key1=TW&key2=".$row->prod_compttr.">".$num2."</a>"; ?>
```

For example if key2 contains "Foto de Vakman" then only Foto is passing to other page.

How to sort this issue out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode strings for a URL, like this:

```
<?php 
  echo "<a href=test2.php?key=".urlencode($row->ean).
       "&key1=TW&key2=".urlencode($row->prod_compttr).
       ">".urlencode($num2)."</a>"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `urlencode`.

```
<?php echo "<a href=test2.php?key=".urlencode($row->ean)."&key1=TW&key2=".urlencode($row->prod_compttr).">".urlencode($num2)."</a>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

URL can never have spaces....so to avoid it, i would suggest replace `" "` with some character and then reversing on `GET` if you have to maintain and use space later on in your page

Simple, Naive and quick way of doing this, if you are unaware of  [**urlencode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Assuming `key` in your URL has `" "`

```
<a href=test2.php?key=".str_replace(' ', '~~~~', $row->ean)."&key1=TW&key2=".$row->prod_compttr.">".$num2."</a>"; ?>
      /* Replace `" "` with `~~~~` here ^^ */
```

then to get the value back on page where you have to fetch

```
$url_key = str_replace("~~~~"," ",  $_GET['key']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are fine, and are generally encoded with +.

To be extra safe, use urlencode() on your values if manually adding them to your params.

```
Ex. $key1 = 'Foto de Vakman';
    echo urlencode($key1); // Foto+de+Vakman
```